# Equal on an open subset implies equal on the whole space?

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be an irreducible algebraic set. Let $U \subset X$ be an open subset with respect to
the Zariski topology over X. Let $f_1 : X \to \mathbb{C}$, $f_2 : X \to \mathbb{C}$ be regular functions on $X$.

Is it true that $f_1|_U = f_2|_U$ implies $f_1 = f_2$?

If yes, how should I proceed to prove it?

Comment: You need to require $U$ to be nonempty. Having required that, the argument goes as follows: The zero set of $f_1 - f_2$ is a closed set of $X$, and (by assumption) contains the nonempty open set $U$. But in an irreducible topological space, if a closed set contains a nonempty set, then this closed set must be the whole space.

Comment: @darijgrinberg: That should be an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if $U$ is nonempty.

Let $Z$ be the zero set of the regular function $f_1 - f_2 : X \to \mathbb{C}$. Then, $Z$ is a closed set (in the topology on $X$). On the other hand, $U$ is an open set, so that $X \setminus U$ is a closed set.

Assume that $U$ is nonempty and that $f_1 \mid_U = f_2 \mid_U$. Then, $\left(f_1 - f_2\right) \mid_U = f_1 \mid_U - f_2 \mid_U = 0$ (since $f_1 \mid_U = f_2 \mid_U$), so that $U \subseteq Z$ (since $Z$ is the zero set of $f_1 - f_2$). Thus, $X = \underbrace{U}_{\subseteq Z} \cup \left(X \setminus U\right) \subseteq Z \cup \left(X \setminus U\right)$. Hence, the topological space $X$ is the union of its two closed sets $Z$ and $X \setminus U$. Hence, one of these two closed sets $Z$ and $X \setminus U$ must be $X$ (because $X$ is irreducible, and therefore, if $X$ is the union of two closed sets, then one of these two closed sets must be $X$). Since $X \setminus U \neq X$ (because $U$ is nonempty), this shows that $Z = X$. But $Z$ was defined as the zero set of $f_1 - f_2$. Therefore, $Z = X$ shows that $f_1 - f_2 = 0$, whence $f_1 = f_2$.